# How to rigorously simplify an expression with Big-Oh Composed within another Big-Oh.

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to show the following:

$$ O(e^{n(\cos n^{-2/5}-1)}) = O(e^{-Cn^{1/5}})$$

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to get a hang of asymptotic notation, and I can't quite figure out how to rigorously (in kinda painful detail) to see how to connect the dots.

I can see that I can expand the inside and write: $\cos n^{-2/5}-1 = -\frac{(n^{-2/5})^2}{2}+O(n^{-8/5})$...and then if I multiply this by $n$ I would get $-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}+O(n^{-3/5})$.

I don't see how to go from $O(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}+O(n^{-3/5})})$ to what I want rigorously, step by step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
O\left(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}+O(n^{-3/5})}\right) = 
O\left(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}}\cdot e^{O(n^{-3/5})}\right) =\\ 
O\left(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}}\cdot e^{O(1)}\right) =
O\left(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}}\cdot O(1)\right) =
O\left(e^{-\frac{n^{1/5}}{2}}\right)
$$
So, in particular, we would take $C = \frac 12$